# Change image on click, keep image and remove if other image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

for an interactive picture i want the images to change on hover and the to keep the hover state if clicked (see the picture here: http://labs.tageswoche.ch/grafik_osze). For the hover i have this code:

```
  var sourceSwap = function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
      $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
      $this.attr('src', newSource);
  }

  $(function() {
      $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
          new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
      }).hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap); 
  });
```

But i dont know how to adpat this code, that it works also on click. If one clicks on another image the original (white picture) should be shown again. So that only one clicked picture is black. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: have you tried $('img').click(sourceSwap);?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mco82kLw/1/

Comment: @abhitalks the jsfiddle doesnt work in firefox, in chrome it works, but the behavior is not exactly what i am looking for. I want all other imgs unclicked / not active when i click on another picture

Comment: @bondythegreat, if i use this code:       $(function() {
          $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
              new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
          }).click(sourceSwap, sourceSwap); 
      });
it is black if i am away, but on hover it is now white and if i click on other elements all elements get black. i want it black on hover and click while using the tooltip and then if i click on another element it becomes white and tooltip disappears (that is already working), i updated the link above

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mffk355y/1/

Comment: @abhitalks nice and simple, but for me it doesnt work with firefox, and also i need to change the pictures, inversion alone doesnt work, i updated the link again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
         var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
         $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
         $this.attr('src', newSource);
      }
  }

var makeActive = function() {
   var $this = $(this);

   // bring the active back (if any) to the first state
   if($('img.active').length) {
      var newSource = $('img.active').data('alt-src');
      $('img.active').data('alt-src', $('img.active').attr('src'));
      $('img.active').attr('src', newSource);

      $('img.active').removeClass('active');
   }

   $this.toggleClass('active');
}


$(function() {
  $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
   new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
  }).hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);

  $('img[data-alt-src]').on('click', makeActive);
});
```

well i havent test it but i hope you got the point

Comment: the hover and click work, but now if i click on it and then on another element, two elements are black, how to remove the class? do i have to put the removeClass to another position? The link is updated

Comment: there is one issue: if you click twice on the same element, this element gets black if you click on another element and then remains black. See updated version: http://labs.tageswoche.ch/grafik_osze/

Comment: please choose the answer as chosen answer (and upvote if it's really working)